# How to treat negative confidence intervals in response scale for GLMM Poisson/negative binomial distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I am using emmeans to produce estimated marginal means from GLMMs with Poisson or negative binomial distributions, but for a few of my models the confidence interval is in the negative. I was not expecting this given the distribution. Can I simply set the lower bound to zero, or am I missing something?

```
m1<-glmmTMB(count ~ treatment + (1|nestBoxSlot), data=data, offset=log(noIndividual), ziformula=~1, family="nbinom2")

emmean <- emmeans(m1, "treatment", type="response", offset=0)
```

Result of emmean

```
  treatment  response        SE  df   lower.CL   upper.CL
1         C 8.1624947 8.0114700 528 -7.5757742 23.9007636
2         M 0.2043217 0.2637268 528 -0.3137608  0.7224043
3        MD 0.4341052 0.5491020 528 -0.6445876  1.5127979
```

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if your software back-transforms the estimates *before* computing the intervals, and then uses the SEs of the back-transformed estimates (usually obtained by the delta method). You can avoid this by computing the intervals on the link scale (e.g., log), and then back-transforming the endpoints.

Comment: BTW, the latter is what the **emmeans** R package does by default. So I am not sure how this happened. Can you show the code you used, and the results?

Comment: Indeed, that is why I was confused. Edited above with an example.

Comment: Odd. Can you tell if the answers are reasonable? What do you get on the link scale? And keep in mind that the estimates don't include the ZI part, I believe. (However, if Ben has revamped it to include the ZI part and estimate the mean response, that *would* involve back-transforming, and would explain everything.

Comment: The estimated response is reasonable, but these are counts of seconds. When I set zero inflation to 0 they are considerably less into the negative.

Comment: I have not been able to find out how emmeans handles calculating CI from zero inflation models in glmmTMB

Comment: The emmeans support methods for those models are in the glmmTMB package, not the emmeans package. The code can be examined by listing   `glmmTMB::emm_basis.glmmTMB`